# How to expose QEMU machine as separate NIC in my LAN?

Tags: networking, qemu

In `Oracle VirtualBox` I can configure my virtual machine so that it is exposed as separate machine on the same `LAN` as the host and it become the same `DHCP` server client as everything in my `LAN`. Also I can connect to virtual machine via ssh from `LAN` etc.

In contrast, the default config on `QEMU` machine gave it `10.0.2.15` address and is not represented in my `LAN`.

How to config it in the same way as VirtualBox?

---

I have added parameter `netdev` parameter and now it has no network at all

```
qemu-system-arm \
    -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie \
    -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio \
    -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
    -hda myimage.img \
    -redir tcp:5022::22 -no-reboot \
    -netdev user,id=mynet0,net=192.168.10.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.10.1
```

---

Changes to VM image should be minimal/zero. Image should be as much close to physically deployable as possible.

Comment: Do the VM:s need to be able to reach the host and vice-versa ? This affects things.  Hair-pin rules in the gateway mitigates this.

Comment: Which `Attached to:` choice in VirtualBox are you using? Bridged Adapter? `qemu` can do this as well, it just requires a little more setup.

Comment: @rfmodulator how?

Comment: @StefanSkoglund if VM is a separate machine in the `LAN`, then how can't it reach the host, which is also separate machine in the `LAN`? it seems to me that the goal implies the answer

Comment: Dims it has to do with how the virtual machine is provisioned with its iface.

Comment: @Dims It has to do with how the virtual network is defined.  mactvtap type iface has that property. See https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TroubleshootMacvtapHostFail .  I got hit with that snag when i transitioned from esxi -> virtualbox -> libvirt .

Comment: What i did on the host is this: create a bridge which has the host iface as a slave. ip addr add 192.168.3.2/24 dev br1 .  In virsh: create a virtual network in bridge mode and connect it to br1, NOT enp1s0 (ie the physical device.)  In the dom definition create a iface with the virtual network as it its net and e1000 (for example as hw.)

Comment: I believe i used virt-manager in the beginning.